# Drupal, embed a view block/result on a custom php page

Tags: php, drupal-7, view

So inside my Drupal root directory I have a custom folder named `/landingpage` and inside there I have a `index.php` page. That page is separate and does share or take anything with drupal. So think of it as a static HTML page that just sits inside a drupal directory.

But now I want to insert a view block that I created from the admin to that static page and I dont know how to proceed from here. I can think of one solution but it does not seem like a clean solution. I was thinking of creating a view with a page display and later embedding it through `<iframe>` in my custom php, but this solution does not sound so good. Tips

Comment: As the static page has nothing to do with your Drupal installation, this is not as straightforward as it would be to include the view/block to a custom Drupal page. Is there a reason you want to keep this page completely separete from Drupal? The first thing that comes to my mind to achieve the desired result would be to create an XML document or some other kind of a feed of the View results and scrape that with PHP on the static page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/extending-drupal-functionality-to-custom-php-page)

So basically adding

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

to the /landingpage/index.php got it to working like I wanted.